# how do you remove the nth item in a list until only one element is left in the list in python

Tags: python, list

So in this program, i have:

```
n = int(input())

p1 = 'One'

p2 = 'Two'

p3 = 'Three'

p4 = 'Four'

p5 = 'Five'


list = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]

while len(list) > 1:
if len(list) > n+1:
    n = n-1
list.pop((n) % len(list))
print (list)
```

For example, `n = 3` and the desired output is `P4` so i have to remove p3. after p3 is removed, i will remove again the nth item but the count will start on the item after the last removed item. since i removed p3, i have to start the count on p4. how do i start the count in p4? the loop i did counts from the very start of the list which is p1.

Comment: Could you add an example of what you are expecting ?

Comment: n = int(input())
p1 = 'one'
p2 = 'two'
p3 = 'three'
p4 = 'four'
p5 = 'five'

list = [p1,p2,p3,p4,p5]

assuming that n = 3, p4 will be removed which makes: list = [p1,p2,p3,p5]

so, the count will start in p5 now. in which p3 will be removed making: list = [p1,p2,p5]

the count will start again in p5 as it is after p3. making list = [p1,p2]

the count will start now in p1 since p1 is after p5 due to wrap list. making list = [p2]

once only one element is left in the list, it will print it.

Comment: Also post what have you tried so far ? There must be minimum effort from your end.

Comment: hey thank you for the suggestion for the edit. i already edited my question and added what i have done so far.

Comment: It is unclear why the result you are getting is not what is desired. Please add desired output.

Comment: hello! im done adding the desired output. i apologize for not adding it earlier, i am quite new in coding and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I edited my suggestion.. hope I understood better what u looking for.

Answer (score -1):

After you initial code, here's the suggestion:

n=3

init_n=1

while len(l) > n+init_n:

```
  l.pop(n+init_n-1)

  init_n = init_n + n -1
```

print (list)

Comment: hi ! thank you for the suggestion. however, the output prints the same thing which is P1